# How to gather information from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL scripting and would be grateful for any assistance on the following;

I need to gather information from various different tables.  I found the information required by running the following scripts.

```
SELECT [immunisation_id]
,[patient_id]
,[course_id]
,[date_due]
,[date_given]
,[result]
,[comments]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[immunisations]

SELECT [course_id]
,[description]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[courses]

SELECT [patient_id]
,[title_id]
,[first_name]
,[last_name]
,[dob]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[patients]

SELECT [title_id]
,[description]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[titles]

SELECT [employee_id]
,[patient_id]
,[post_title_id]
,[department_id]
,[directorate_id]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[employees]

SELECT [post_title_id]
,[description]
 FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[post_titles]

SELECT [department_id]
,[description]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[departments]
```

I now need to return results on patients who have had immunisations only and include information from the following tables & columns;

```
description from dbo.titles
first_name, last_name, dob from dbo.patients
description from dbo.post_titles
description from dbo.departments
description from dbo.courses
date_due, date given, result, comments from dbo.immunisations
```

I have read that inner joins will do this but don't know how to compile the script.

Comment: Your example is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the SQL is valid one. All the tables are connected. Check my answer for details.

Comment: @pro_cheats: no. The `[` and `]` are invalid in an identifier in **standard** SQL - which is what the `sql` tag refers to. It is valid in certain dialects (database products), but not in standard SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh yeah the syntax. I thought they were put for understanding and were to be omitted by default. I thought you pointed out some logical error.

Comment: Check out `JOIN` and `UNION ALL`, real basics...

Comment: I've been using ms sql studio 2012

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to join from multiple tables -

```
SELECT a.description, b.description, c.description, d.first_name --(so on.. and other columns you need)
from TABLEA as a
INNER JOIN TABLEB as b
     on a.commonattribute = b.commonattribute
INNER JOIN TABLEC as c
    on a.commonattribute = c.commonattribute or b.commonattribute = c.commonatribute
--so on to all the required tables...

WHERE (some condition)
ORDER BY (some column);
```

So in your case, (took a while to combine all tables)

```
SELECT 

p.patient_id
,p.title_id
,p.first_name
,p.last_name
,p.dob

,i.immunisation_id
,i.course_id
,i.date_due
,i.date_given
,i.result
,i.comments

,c.description

,t.description

,e.employee_id
,e.post_title_id
,e.department_id
,e.directorate_id

,p_t.description

,d.description

FROM Cohort.dbo.patients p

inner join Cohort.dbo.immunisations i
ON i.patient_id = p.patient_id

inner join  Cohort.dbo.courses c
ON c.course_id = i.course_id

inner join  Cohort.dbo.titles t
ON t.title_id = p.title_id

inner join  Cohort.dbo.employees e
ON t.patient_id = p.patient_id

inner join  Cohort.dbo.post_titles p_t
ON p_t.post_title_id = e.post_title_id

inner join  Cohort.dbo.departments d
ON d.department_id = e.department_id
```

This should Work :D

Comment: @LJEAN could you check this answer once and mark it as an answer if it works?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response.  Unfortunately it didn't work.  I thought the following might work as well but didn't. SELECT

SELECT [immunisation_id]
,[date_due]
,[date_given]
,[result]
,[comments]
FROM [Cohort].[dbo].[immunisations]

INNER JOIN [Cohort].[dbo].[courses] ON [course_id] = [description]

INNER JOIN  [Cohort].[dbo].[patients] ON [first_name]=[first_name]
,[last_name]=[last_name], [dob]=[dob]

INNER JOIN [Cohort].[dbo].[titles] ON [title_id]=[description]

INNER JOIN [Cohort].[dbo].[departments] ON [department_id]
= [description]

Comment: Kindly check your joining clauses. For example `course_id = description` is wrong. Both columns need to be of same data type when you equate them and needs to have few/all same values logically.

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to say thank you for taking so much time to look compiling this script.  It has been extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

First off, select from the table you want to define the rest. In this case, immunusations

```
select date_due, date_given, result, comments
from dbo.immunisations i1 -- give it an alias
-- the joins will go in here
where date_given is not null -- this excludes the records where the immunisation has not yet happened
```

Ok, now let's start joining:

```
select i1.date_due, i1.date_given, i1.result, i1.comments,
       p2.first_name, p2.last_name, p2.dob
from dbo.immunisations i1
inner join dbo.patients p2
  on p2.patient_id = i1.patient_id -- aliases make it easier to join
where date_given is not null
```

Unfortunately, you lack a way of joining the employee info to the immunisation (from your provided code, anyway), so you will need to take this logic, find the missing links and apply it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  I have now begun using aliases in my scripts to make it easier to join.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your input.  It was very much appreciated. After reading them all and watching a few tutorials I managed to figure it out;  This is what worked. I also wanted to point out that [] is microsoft specific for those few that didn't know.  However I did think it was a good idea to remove them since the script can be used for say an Oracle environment.

select *

from patients

join immunisations
on patients.patient_id = immunisations.patient_id

join titles
on patients.title_id = titles.title_id

join courses
on immunisations.course_id = courses.course_id

join departments
on patients.patient_id = departments.department_id

join employees
on patients.patient_id = employees.post_title_id

Best regards

Louise